# How to call a method while app is kill/terminate/suspended in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to get the list of new events, so continuously I need to call a service while I am near by the event. then only I can send my uid and eventide by API call then backend team notify that you are near by event.
So this service how to call while app kill/terminate/suspended because these things working while app in background.

Comment: There is very little you can do if the app is terminated. Your best bet is to use significant location change monitoring and push notifications from your bs lend when there are updated event details. Polling is not efficient from a battery or network use perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow a silent notification way if feasible in your app flow, whenever you need to call a method you can send a silent notification to the device,

- Device get the silent notification which won't sound like push notification,
- your app will be wake up in the background and at that time,
- You can call your method.

```swift
func registerForNotification() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            guard error == nil else { return }
            if granted {
                //Register for RemoteNotifications. Your Remote Notifications can display alerts now :)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            }
            else {
                //Handle user denying permissions..
            }
        }
        providerDelegate = ProviderDelegate()
        pushRegistry.delegate = self
        pushRegistry.desiredPushTypes = [.voIP]
    }
func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate credentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {
//Here you get the token, send it to server.
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a best-effort kind of feature. If the user has bg refresh turned off, the battery is almost empty, or for any other reason, iOS can decide to delay or omit the delivery of the notification to your app. You should also not send more that 2-3 notifications per hour according to Apple's docs. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

Comment: You can't use voip pushes unless you are going to indicate that there is an incoming voip call. If your app fails to indicate an incoming voip call using CallKit in iOS 13 it will be terminated and will not receive any further push notifications.  You can use normal silent push notifications, but these will not execute if the user has terminated your app.

Comment: @Paulw11  Can we use other pushes type for this task?

Comment: There are no other push types that will relaunch a terminated app